# ipython - "cannot import name 'create_prompt_application' from 'prompt_toolkit.shortcuts'

Tags: windows, ipython

I'm trying to get ipython working on my windows 10 64 bit computer. When I try to start ipython from the command line, I get the error pictured in the screenshot attached to this question.

Has anyone encountered this? How I might I fix this problem?

[image: Ipython Error]

Answer (score 48):

This problem is caused by having a newer version of Prompt Toolkit installed than is depended upon by IPython. (Version 2.0.4 of Prompt Toolkit is installed and IPython requires version 1.0.15.)

You can rectify this issue by installing an older, compatible version of prompt-toolkit with pip (or pip3):

```
pip3 install 'prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.15' --force-reinstall
```

(If you install or upgrade Prompt Toolkit past 1.0.15—the last 1.x version—you will receive a warning from pip: `ipython 6.5.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.15, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 2.0.4 which is incompatible.`)

Answer (score 20):

You can just reinstall the ipython, that will solve the `'prompt-toolkit'` problem automatically.

```
pip install ipython
```

Answer (score 11):

This can also be a solution

```
pip3 install --upgrade ipython
```

if you are working with python3. Or,

```
pip3 install ipython
```

This solves some problems of missing kernel to, at least on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

`pip install ipython` worked for me:)

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was an old installation of IPython when I installed juptyer. So `pip install -U ipython`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run

```
pip install --user ipython
```

to make it work if your user does not have admin rights.

Comment: Your explanation is grammatically a bit unclear. Could you maybe rephrase it a little?

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem with this commands

`sudo -H pip3 install fs`

`sudo -H pip3 install prompt-toolkit --force-reinstall`

`pip3 install prompt-toolkit --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using conda to set virtual environment with a default python version (Python 3.6.4).

Creating the conda environment and forcing any specific python version (even the same version as the problematic default):

```
conda create -n test_env python=3.6.4
```

solved it.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me: 
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed -U ipython

Answer (score 0):

try pip install prompt-toolkit==1.0.15. works on windows

Answer (score 0):

For those of us who get an error

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
mssql-cli 1.0.0 requires click<7.1,>=4.1, but you have click 8.1.3 which is incompatible.
mssql-cli 1.0.0 requires prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0, but you have prompt-toolkit 3.0.38 which is incompatible.
```

or get this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'KeyPressEvent' from 'prompt_toolkit.key_binding' (/home/olaf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/key_binding/__init__.py)
   (file "/home/olaf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/terminal/shortcuts/auto_match.py", line 8, in <module>)
```

to avoid breaking existing python package version setup just create a new python virtual environment

```
pip install virtualenv                  #  install package which can create new virt environments
python -m virtualenv venv_this_example  #  create virt environment
source venv_this_example/bin/activate   #  engage virt env
pip3 install 'prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.15' --force-reinstall # issue python package install command which only impacts this specific virt env and not entire host box python package install ecosystem
```

notice in above it create new directory

```
venv_this_example/bin/activate
```

which isolates python packages installed to ONLY effecting this specific virt env